# How to append an image dynamically generated with base64 to form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

1. Now I had a form with several input elements. `myForm`
2. And an image dynamically generated with base64 like this:

   ```
   const image = document.createElement("img")
   image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + response[i].base64Code
   image.style.width = 300;
   image.style.height = 300;
   imageDiv.appendChild(image)
   ```
3. When submitting the form, append the image:

   ```
   myForm.append('myImage', image)  // How to append the image source to the form?
   ```
4. `myForm.submit()`

Comment: please include part of your html code

Comment: First of all you can not submit the contents of an image tag. You should use the input tag and sent its type to file. You will also have to set its name to a value otherwise it is not going to be submitted to the server.